# Commands hangs on logical volume

Tags: linux, lvm, mount, boot, opensuse

I'm using virtual machine with **SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11**. After one of the critical shutdowns of the server, the **disk id** have changed. I have changed and replaced the values with new ones in the following files:

```
/boot/grub/menu.lst
/boot/grub/device.map
```

In `/etc/fstab` /dev/sda* was specified, so there was no need to change it. But there was an error during boot:

```
mount: special device /dev/u01/u01_lv does not exist
failed
```

**lvdisplay** output:

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/u01/u01_lv
  VG Name                u01
  LV UUID                JofgN1-bFZD-9VYg-WT49-UJOe-Swdq-aCx7dZ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                40.00 GiB
  Current LE             10240
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

I activated with command `vgchange -ay` and remounted it. But when trying to create a file, delete, open a text file, etc. on this disk, the command **hangs**.

I'm also tried `dd if=/dev/sda4 of=/dev/null bs=1M` and it works fine.

**pvs** output:

```
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda4  u01  lvm2 a-   40.00g    0
```

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 75.2 GB, 75161927680 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9137 cylinders, total 146800640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xaa571b60

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      208895      103424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          208896    58718207    29254656   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        58718208    62910463     2096128   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4        62910464   146800639    41945088   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders, total 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

**dmsetup info /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv**

```
Name:              u01-u01_lv
State:             ACTIVE
Read Ahead:        1024
Tables present:    LIVE
Open count:        1
Event number:      0
Major, minor:      253, 0
Number of targets: 1
UUID: LVM-LvAgWmBsFAxRrv0YEosS6WuUcfKwnsa9JofgN1bFZD9VYgWT49UJOeSwdqaCx7dZ
```

Comment: This might be the problem: Disk /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: maybe the underlying hardware has a problem. Have you checked the hardware disks? Do you have RAID under LVM?

Comment: no, we don't have RAID.

Comment: I also found several posts saying that I can ignore message 
"Disk /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv doesn't contain a valid partition table"

Comment: What is the output of `dmsetup info /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv`?

Comment: Your logical volume does not need a partition table. The main concern is LV Status. What happens if you do `lvchange -ay /dev/u01/u01_lv`

Comment: After execution `lvchange -ay /dev/u01/u01_lv`  `LV Status` is changed to `available` and i can mount this logical volume, but when trying to create a file, delete, open a text file, etc. on this disk, the command hangs.